# If a value in a variable increases by a specific number, do:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Maybe I am thinking about this wrong:

When I scrape a site i get 3 values. I would like to print those values to excel and that it prints the 3 values in 3 following cells and then changes row, print 3 values changes row and so on.

So here is what i got so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl



r = requests.get("https://www.hemnet.se/bostader? 
location_ids%5B%5D=18045&item_types%5B%5D=bostadsratt")



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")



rad = 2
kol = 1


for pris_kvd_rum in soup.find_all("div", class_="listing-card__attribute 
listing-card__attribute--primary"):


  pris = pris_kvd_rum.text


  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("hemnet.xlsx")
  ws = wb.active

  ws.cell(row = rad, column = kol).value = pris


  kol += 1

  if kol % 4 == 0:
    rad +=1



wb.save("hemnet.xlsx")
```

Comment: `kol == kol + 4` will never be true. An integer cannot be equal to itself plus 4. What did you intend for this to do?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something every 4th iteration you can use:

```
if kol % 4 == 0:
...
```

Instead of `if kol == kol + 4:` which is never `True`.